# Show a different code on front page to other pages

Tags: php, templates, frontpage

I'm looking to display a list of posts in the header section on my template on all pages with the exception of the front page where I would like to show an image in place of the list of posts.

Is there a function within wordpress to detect the front page that I can use in my template code? or should I just be looking at PHP code that says if the URL matches X then show this, else show the other code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [wordpress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to do just that. Specifically, you can put the code you want in `front-page.php` and then use `index.php` for the rest of them, though that's a rather bland way of doing design with what you have on your hands.

Alternately, there are the [wordpress conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) which can be used to detect whether you're on a category page or the frontpage, etc.

#### Edit

Using the `is_front_page()` conditional:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // This is the site front page;
    // put your front-page output here
} else {
    // Put your default output here
}
?>
```

Comment: The list will be shown in the header so the template hierarchy isn't an option. I'll have a look at the conditional tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways you could do this:

1. Create a page called home with your image in it (or use a custom page template with your image in it) then set that as your home page in the "Settings > Reading" section in the admin.
2. Create a template file with your desired content and call it `front-page.php`