# Only show div on homepage/blog index in wordpress/php

Tags: php

I have a wordpress site. I have a div that I only want to appear on the homepage (in the header). What type of php if statement do i need...

In other words:

only show  ....  in the header of the main blog index page. Problem is the header itself is loaded in every page.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a different code on front page to other pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44489/show-a-different-code-on-front-page-to-other-pages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

```
<?php if(is_home()): ?>

<div>Your div.</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks.. my problem is that my theme effectively sets the homepage to display a "category". Is there a similar statement like (is_category_XXXX)?

Comment: @NKeating Did this not work?

Comment: it hid the div from the homepage because it does not detect it as home.. In other words, the homepage is set to display a category index called videos. See URL: http://speedsociety.com/

Comment: and im trying to display a "featured video" div above the main index but only on the homepage.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive

Comment: Also try: `is_front_page()`.

Comment: Also try: reading all of codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/ There's some handy stuff on there.

Comment: You **definitely** want to use **`is_front_page()`** rather than `is_home()`. The former corresponds to the **Site Front Page**; the latter corresponds to the **Blog Posts Index**, which *may or may not* be on the site front page.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php if(is_home()): ?>

<div>Your div.</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Using above code works fine as long as you are not setting static Page for the Front Page display from here Administration > Settings > Reading.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>

<div>Your div.</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But this code will work irrespective of whether the main blog page is showing or you have set a static page to show on home page.

Answer (score 1):

You could also solve the problem with CSS.

Set the div to

```
#your-div{
display: none;
}
```

in your css.

Then find the body class page-id for the front page and set the css for that as:

```
.body-class-page-id #your-div {
display: block;
}
```

This will hide it on every page except the page you want to show it on.

Comment: This actually ended up making more sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's always `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you can use to determine which page you're at. For homepage it is usually just '/'. so:

```
<?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) { ?>
<div id="home_only">Content goes here..</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: a) What about `index.php`? and b) that type of solution won't really work with Wordpress.

Comment: a) I don't see a reason why anyone would let people to view their homepage like http://domain.com/index.php b) What makes you think it won't work?

Comment: ...Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works like a charm.